# Is this correct approach to proving $xy=0$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Is this a sufficient way of proving that for for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, if $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$?

My attempt:

$$xy=0$$ 
$$y=\frac{0}{x}$$

$$x=\frac{0}{y}$$

Is this a correct approach using axioms of real numbers?

Comment: A mathematical proof consists of logical *statements*, not just symbols.

Comment: Perhaps you want to prove that if $x\not=0$, then $y$ must be zero.

Comment: Well you can only divide by $x$ if you're sure that $x$ *isn't* zero, and the same goes for $y$, so you need to be a bit more careful about that. But you could combine this with what Michael Burr said.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ and $y$ be two real numbers and suppose $xy=0$. There are two cases:

- $x=0$;
- $x\ne 0$.

If $x=0$, then "$x=0$ or $y=0$" is true.

If $x\neq 0$, then $x^{-1}$ exists and multiplying this number on both sides of $xy=0$ gives $y=0$, which implies that "$x=0$ or $y=0$" is true.